# How do I Create a Full Install of Windows 10 to USB Device from Ubuntu 20.04 Step by Step?

Tags: usb, live-usb

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 as my daily driver. Unfortunately I need to run some Windows programs that require too much RAM to work well in a virtual machine. I would like to avoid dual booting to preserve storage. Therefore I would like to make a full install of Windows 10 on a USB drive. Is that possible from Ubuntu 20.04, and if so how?

Thank you!

Comment: Umm … regardless of *where* the installation sits, having  your computer able to boot multiple OSes from multiple locations is still multi (or dual) booting. Are you just aiming to avoid resizing partitions?

Comment: Yes more or less. Like I said in the question, I don't want to add an additional partition on my SSD as I don't have enough storage.

Answer (score 5):

### Create a Full Install of Windows 10 to USB Device from Ubuntu 20.04 Step by Step?

**Warning: This question will likely be closed as off-topic**

1. Boot Ubuntu and open Windows 10 in VirtualBox
2. Download Windows ISO from Microsoft, (1803, 1909 and 20H2 should work)
3. Download Rufus
4. Start Rufus and run **"Windows To Go"** Image option
5. Reboot to USB and Windows Setup should run automatically.

This may take a long time and works much better on some flash drives than on others, SSD's are recommended.

[image]

You can dual boot the USB with Ubuntu if you want to make this question a little more about Ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Quick question: Why do I need the Windows 1909 ISO specifically? It should work just the same with any other iso right?

Comment: I tested it with the 1909 ISO and it worked. I tried it with 1903 and Rufus complained and would not accept it. Try what ever version you have, Rufus will let you know if it works or not. I read that it works with 1803 but not 1809. I have not tried it with 20H2, will try that later, after my latest trial is done. Will update the answer.

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful!

Comment: One last question before I begin: will I be able to update Windows this way?

Comment: I read that it is not possible to upgrade versions, I have not tried yet.

Comment: @Pentaquark: 20H2 worked for me with Rufus WTG. The installer did not ask for any numbers. The installer did an update before running Setup.